# Change the data that appears in textview through holder and RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Please help me in solving this problem, as I am currently working on an application that performs tasks at certain times and days, as I keep the days in which the implementation will be carried out in a database in the form of numbers and when they are reviewed in the application I want to show instead of those numbers the name of the days based on a condition that depends on its number (if the number 1 is returned, the name of that day should appear, not this number)
Please help me to implement this thing as I tried assigning the value to a variable but the name of the day does not appear in (RecyclerView).

This is "CustomAdapter" code

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList Id, Active, Type_Id, DateCreated , Event_Id , Hour , Minute, SAT ,
SUN , MON , TUS  , WED , THU , FRI , Execute_Id , DateModifed ;

String SAT_Id = "0";
//String SAT_name = "0" ;

CustomAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList Id, ArrayList Active,
              ArrayList Type_Id, ArrayList DateCreated , ArrayList Event_Id, ArrayList Hour,
              ArrayList Minute, ArrayList SAT ,ArrayList SUN, ArrayList MON, ArrayList TUS ,
              ArrayList WED, ArrayList THU, ArrayList FRI , ArrayList Execute_Id , ArrayList DateModifed){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = context;

    this.Id = Id;
    this.Active = Active;
    this.Type_Id = Type_Id;
    this.DateCreated = DateCreated;
    this.Event_Id = Event_Id;
    this.Hour = Hour;
    this.Minute = Minute;
    this.SAT = SAT;
    this.SUN = SUN;
    this.MON = MON;
    this.TUS = TUS;
    this.WED = WED;
    this.THU = THU;
    this.FRI = FRI;
    this.Execute_Id = Execute_Id;
    this.DateModifed = DateModifed;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.db_times_my_rows, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    String Exec_stat_Id = String.valueOf(Event_Id.get(position));
    String Exec_stat_name = "" ;

    if(String.valueOf(Event_Id.get(position)) == "-1")
    {
        Exec_stat_name = "Not" ;
    }
    else if(String.valueOf(Event_Id.get(position)) == "2")
    {
        Exec_stat_name = "Video" ;
    }

    SAT_Id = String.valueOf(SAT.get(position));
    String SAT_name = "-1" ;
    if(SAT_Id == "0")
    {
        SAT_name = " " ;
    }
    else if(SAT_Id == "1")
    {
        SAT_name = "SAT" ;
    }


    holder.Id_txt.setText(String.valueOf(Id.get(position)));
    //holder.name_txt.setText("Name: " + Exec_stat_name);
    holder.name_txt.setText(Exec_stat_name);
    holder.Time_txt.setText(String.valueOf(Hour.get(position)) + " : " + String.valueOf(Minute.get(position)));
    //holder.SAT_txt.setText(String.valueOf(SAT.get(position)));
    holder.SAT_txt.setText(SAT_name);
    //MyViewHolder.notifyDataSetChanged();
    holder.SUN_txt.setText(String.valueOf(SUN.get(position)));
    holder.MON_txt.setText(String.valueOf(MON.get(position)));
    holder.TUS_txt.setText(String.valueOf(TUS.get(position)));
    holder.WED_txt.setText(String.valueOf(WED.get(position)));
    holder.THU_txt.setText(String.valueOf(THU.get(position)));
    holder.FRI_txt.setText(String.valueOf(FRI.get(position)));

    //Recyclerview onClickListener
    holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Times_Insert_Update.class);

            intent.putExtra("Id", String.valueOf(Id.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("Active", String.valueOf(Active.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("Type_Id", String.valueOf(Type_Id.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("DateCreated", String.valueOf(DateCreated.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("Event_Id", String.valueOf(Event_Id.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("Hour", String.valueOf(Hour.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("Minute", String.valueOf(Minute.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("SAT", String.valueOf(SAT.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("SUN", String.valueOf(SUN.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("MON", String.valueOf(MON.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("TUS", String.valueOf(TUS.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("WED", String.valueOf(WED.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("THU", String.valueOf(THU.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("FRI", String.valueOf(FRI.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("Execute_Id", String.valueOf(Execute_Id.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("DateModifed", String.valueOf(DateModifed.get(position)));

            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Id.size();
}
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout mainLayout;

    TextView Id_txt, name_txt, Time_txt, SAT_txt , SUN_txt , MON_txt, TUS_txt, WED_txt,
            THU_txt, FRI_txt;

    MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Id_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Id_txt);
        name_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
        Time_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Time_txt);
        SAT_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.SAT_txt);
        SUN_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.SUN_txt);
        MON_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.MON_txt);
        TUS_txt= itemView.findViewById(R.id.TUS_txt);
        WED_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.WED_txt);
        THU_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.THU_txt);
        FRI_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FRI_txt);

        mainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        Animation translate_anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.translate_anim);
        mainLayout.setAnimation(translate_anim);
    }
}
```

}

This is "Recyclerview_activity" code

```
public class Times_Recyclerview extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
Button add_button;
ImageView empty_imageview;
TextView no_data;
CustomAdapter customAdapter;
MyDatabaseHelper myDB;

ArrayList<String> Id, Active, Type_Id, DateCreated , Event_Id , Hour , Minute , SAT ,
        SUN , MON , TUS  , WED , THU , FRI , Execute_Id , DateModifed ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.db_times_recyclerview);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    add_button = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    empty_imageview = findViewById(R.id.empty_imageview);
    no_data = findViewById(R.id.no_data);

    add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Times_Recyclerview.this, Times_Insert_Update.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(Times_Recyclerview.this);

    Id = new ArrayList<>();
    Active = new ArrayList<>();
    Type_Id = new ArrayList<>();
    DateCreated = new ArrayList<>();
    Event_Id = new ArrayList<>();
    Hour = new ArrayList<>();
    Minute = new ArrayList<>();
    SAT = new ArrayList<>();
    SUN = new ArrayList<>();
    MON = new ArrayList<>();
    TUS = new ArrayList<>();
    WED = new ArrayList<>();
    THU = new ArrayList<>();
    FRI = new ArrayList<>();
    Execute_Id = new ArrayList<>();
    DateModifed = new ArrayList<>();

    storeDataInArrays();

    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(Times_Recyclerview.this,this, Id,
            Active, Type_Id, DateCreated , Event_Id , Hour , Minute, SAT ,
            SUN , MON , TUS  , WED , THU , FRI , Execute_Id , DateModifed);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Times_Recyclerview.this));
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1)
    {
        recreate();
    }
}

void storeDataInArrays(){
    Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0)
    {
        empty_imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){

            Id.add(cursor.getString(0));
            Active.add(cursor.getString(1));
            Type_Id.add(cursor.getString(2));
            DateCreated.add(cursor.getString(3));
            Event_Id.add(cursor.getString(4));
            Hour.add(cursor.getString(5));
            Minute.add(cursor.getString(6));
            SAT.add(cursor.getString(7));
            SUN.add(cursor.getString(8));
            MON.add(cursor.getString(9));
            TUS.add(cursor.getString(10));
            WED.add(cursor.getString(11));
            THU.add(cursor.getString(12));
            FRI.add(cursor.getString(13));
            Execute_Id.add(cursor.getString(14));
            DateModifed.add(cursor.getString(15));

        }
        empty_imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        no_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.times_my_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_all){
        confirmDialog();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

void confirmDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Delete All?");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete all Data?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(Times_Recyclerview.this);
            myDB.deleteAllData();
            //Refresh Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Times_Recyclerview.this, Times_Recyclerview.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

}

This is "my_row" XML code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Id_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:text="Title 1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Id_txt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/id_txt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Time_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name_txt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/id_txt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SAT_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SAT"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Id_txt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_txt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SUN_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SUN"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/SAT_txt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_txt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MON_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MON"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/SUN_txt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_txt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TUS_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TUS"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/MON_txt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_txt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/WED_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WED"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TUS_txt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_txt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/THU_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="THU"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/WED_txt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_txt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/FRI_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FRI"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/THU_txt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_txt" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is "RecyclerView" XML code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DB.Times_Recyclerview">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="390dp"
            android:layout_height="650dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/empty_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
            android:alpha="0.1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_empty"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:text="No Data."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_button"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/add1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"

    android:lineSpacingExtra="36sp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"

    android:text="+"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:iconPadding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

---

**Update : **

I searched for you and did not find any solution that works this thing, but after the experiments I made another textview (Called here: SUN_no_txt) for each day so that it carries the value of the result retrieved from the database and then through this textview the condition is made that will set the value I want, then hide this textview, thus this temporarily solved the problem (I know this is an unprofessional solution but this gave me the result I wanted)

```
holder.SUN_no_txt.setText(String.valueOf(SAT.get(position)));

if(holder.SUN_no_txt.getText().toString().equals("-1") || holder.SUN_no_txt.getText().toString().equals("0"))
        {
            holder.SUN_txt.setText("");
        }
        else if(holder.SUN_no_txt.getText().toString().equals("1"))
        {
            holder.SUN_txt.setText("SUNDAY");
        }
        holder.SUN_no_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);  // To hide
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DateUtil{
      private static final List<String> DAYS_IN_WEEK = new ArrayList<>();

      static{
         DAYS_IN_WEEK.add("SUNDAY");
         DAYS_IN_WEEK.add("MONDAY");
         DAYS_IN_WEEK.add("TUESDAY");
         DAYS_IN_WEEK.add("WEDNESDAY");
         DAYS_IN_WEEK.add("THRUSDAY");
         DAYS_IN_WEEK.add("FRIDAY");
         DAYS_IN_WEEK.add("SATURDAY");
      }
      public static String getDayByPosition(Integer position){
            return (position != null && 
                    position >= 0 && 
                    position < DAYS_IN_WEEK.size())?
                     DAYS_IN_WEEK.get(position) : "INVALID DAY";
      }
}
```

When you need to get the name of the day and you only have the position use this utility class and function.

In a unrelated topic you would get a lot of benefit from combining information into one data model like so.

```
public class Time{
    private String id;
    private String active;
    private String typeId;
    private String dateCreated;
    private String eventId;
    private String hour;
    private String minute;
    private String saturday;
    private String sunday;
    private String monday;
    private String tuesday;
    private String wednesday;
    private String thursday;
    private String friday;
    private String executeId;
    private String dateModifed;
    public Time(
          String id,
          String active,
          String typeId,
          String dateCreated,
          String eventId,
          String hour,
          String minute,
          String saturday,
          String sunday,
          String monday,
          String tuesday,
          String wednesday,
          String thursday,
          String friday,
          String executeId,
          String dateModifed
    )
    //getters and setters
}
```

That way you can pass around your data in a more appropriate manner.

```
List<Times> times = new ArrayList<>();

new CustomAdapter(this,times);
```

Also all of your model data members are Strings which can be `Serializable`/`Parcelable` easily by implementing either of those interfaces.

When you pass an `Intent` all you would have to do is

`intent.putExtra("time", time);`

and when you retrieve it

`Time time = (Time)intent.getSerializableExtra("time");`

OR (depending on the `interface` that `Time` implements)

`Time time = intent.getParcelableExtra("time");`

Comment: Hello..
I prefer that the same codes that I set be violated because they are linked to other codes and it will be difficult to change according to your response